# Use Arrows keys to highlight selected row

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web, html-table

I need your help,

The code below is used to highlight the selected (clicked) row from the grid table. However, how can it modified such that when the focus is on the table and I use both the arrow up and down keys it will highlight and go to the next (down key) or previous row (up key). I am still a newbie to this all and have had previous help with the existing coding.

Any help is greatly and most appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-ca">
    <title>Scrolling Data Grid</title>
<style>
/* ==================================================================== */
/* SCROLLING DATA GRID                                                  */
/* ==================================================================== */
DIV.scrollingdatagrid {
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
}
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE {
    width : 98.7%; /* Make room for scroll bar! */
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    border-collapse:separate;
}
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE TR .locked, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE THEAD TR, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE TFOOT TR {
    position:relative;
}
/* OffsetParent of the TR is the DIV because it is position:relative */
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE THEAD TR {
    top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
}


/* Make the z-index values very clear so overlaps happen as expected! */
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TD, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TH { z-index:1; }
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TD.locked, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TH.locked { z-index:2; }
DIV.scrollingdatagrid THEAD TR, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TFOOT TR { z-index:3; }
DIV.scrollingdatagrid THEAD TR TH.locked { z-index:4; }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { 

var cn      =   new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")
var rs      =   new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset")
var dbFile  =   "imts.mdb"
var dbPath  =   "F:\\PROJECTS\\IMTS PROJECT\\V8\\database\\"

var mySQL   = "SELECT * FROM tbl_imts WHERE [FILE NUMBER] LIKE '%99%'"
var html    = ""

cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + dbPath + dbFile + "");
rs.Open(mySQL, cn, 1, 3)

html += '<table id="mstrTable" style="table-layout: fixed; font-family: arial; font-size: 9pt;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">\n'
html += '<thead>\n'
html += '<tr>\n'
html += '<th class="locked" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); text-align: center; height: 30px; width: 20px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">#</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(0).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(1).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(2).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(3).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(4).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(5).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(6).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(7).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(8).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(9).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(10).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(11).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(12).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(13).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(14).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: none; padding-left: 5px; width: 100px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(15).name + '</th>\n'
html += '</tr>\n'
html += '</thead>\n'

rs.MoveFirst
var i = 0
html += '<tbody>\n'
while (!rs.eof) {
++i
html += '<tr style="color: rgb(102,102,102)">\n'
html += '<td class="locked" style="height: 20px; text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);">'+i+'.</td>\n'
    for (var r = 0; r < rs.fields.count; ++r) {
    if (!rs.fields(r).value) { rs.fields(r).value = "&nbsp;" }
    html    +=  '<td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">'+rs.fields(r).value+'</td>\n'
    }//end of for
    html    +=  '</tr>\n'
    rs.MoveNext 
    }//end of while
html += '</tbody>\n'
html += '</table>\n'

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = html


var color = "#E1E0D7"
var rows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
var n = rows.length;
var bgcs = [];
for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) bgcs[i] = rows[i].style.backgroundColor;

function changeColor(e) {
if(!e) e = window.event;
var o = e.target? e.target: e.srcElement;
while(o.tagName && o.tagName.toLowerCase()!="tr") o = o.parentNode;
    for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = bgcs[i];
        if(rows[i]==o) {
        rows[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
        }//end of if
    }//end of for
}//end of function

if(document.addEventListener) for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) rows[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor, false);
else for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) rows[i].attachEvent("onclick", changeColor);
}//end of onload



</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="p1" class="scrollingdatagrid" style="width:800px;height:200px;border:1px solid rgb(128,128,128);"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's an interesting reading about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure entirely how to do it in html or css but in JavaScript it is easily feasible.  I would start out with a hidden highlight behind each element.  Then you simply keep track of which element you are on and take in when an arrow is keydowned.  When that action happens the current element's highlight can be hidden and the next element's highlight can be unhidden.  You would need a function for each direction and/or each element.

Comment: Did you successfully implement it?